# What's the best way to create a seccomp whitelist for LXC

Tags: security, lxc, linux-audit

I try to setup a very restrictive seccomp whitelist for a busybox based LXC container. I started with the file `/usr/share/doc/lxc/examples/seccomp-v1.conf` from Ubuntu. It seems to contain most useful syscalls, but doesn't seem to be further documented.

I started my containers using this file and almost everything worked, only `nginx` didn't start. Using `strace` I discovered that two syscalls were missing (something with `*pid*`/`*gid*`). `ausyscall` helped me translating the names to numbers. After that, `nginx` started.

Now, I want to reduce the file to what is really necessary. For this, I wrote a script which loops through the file, removes one line temporarily and tests if all features still work in the container. At the end, it is able to create a new (more restrictive) whitelist.

As this process is very time consuming, it was running every night last week with several iterations. Currently I got stuck because `lxc-attach fails providing an interactive console`. I try to find a faster way for debugging, best would be if syslog or Lxc logs all seccomp violations.

I tried to set `audit=1` on the kernel command line, but only once I saw seccomp-related audit messages in syslog. Lxc in contrast only shows "Container violated seccomp" which doesn't help me finding which syscall is the problem. **Update:** If `auditd` is installed, the logs are written to `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and the kernel command line parameter is not checked anymore.

**Q:** Is there a more efficient way for generating a useful seccomp whitelist? And are there recommendations what to block beside the lxc-default `kexec_load`, `open_by_handle_at`, `init_module`, `finit_module` and `delete_module`? Is there a list of dangerous syscalls?

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, I discovered that the seccomp audit log now go to `/var/log/audit/audit.log` instead of syslog, after I installed `auditd` which for getting the ausyscall tool. Without the tool, the logs don't go anywhere.

The file contains lines like

```
type=SECCOMP msg=audit(1444422928.758:649196): auid=0 uid=100033 gid=100033 ses=1 pid=18459 comm="nginx" exe="/usr/sbin/nginx" sig=31 arch=c000003e syscall=288 compat=0 ip=0x7f2f71555467 code=0x0
```

Which clearly say which process and which syscall violated the rules - this helps me much.

But I leave this quesion open. There are still unanswered questions and I'm still looking for a more efficient way to set up such a whitelist file than by try&error.